# Why do some people cut concrete before they break a hole in it?

Tags: concrete, demolition

I'm replacing a shower drain. I notice some people cut the foundation with a concrete wet saw before they jack hammer the foundation to get through it. Others, don't. Is there a benefit to cutting the foundation first?

Answer (score 10):

It helps to confine the breakage to a more defined area, by providing a stress concentration and weak point at the edge of the area you want to remove.

A side effect is that **because** it concentrates the stress, it makes breaking out the chunk you want easier (the force is not distributed to the whole slab if it hits a cut line and starts making cracks below it.)

Comment: Yep, it's basically like nibbling out a notch cut on a tile using a wetsaw, instead of trying to notch it using pliers or something.